# Proteus error:logic race conditions detected during transient analysis

Tags: divide, alu, digital-design

I’m trying to design a simple alu that get two 5-bit number and return the result of adding them or subtract or multiply or divide.
With using ICs ,it goes well.However I want to design everything myself.
In designing divide I get error :
logic race conditions detected during transient analysis

It happens when I tried implementing 4-bit magnitude compartor.
This module work properly but in this project came to  get error.

I use this module multiple times but just in this part came to get error.
Please help me to solve this error!!

Comment: Please construct and post the associated 4-bit magnitude compartor Karnaugh-map (kmap).  This kmap "permits the rapid identification and elimination of potential race conditions" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).  Apparently, there are three possible sets of these groups per "This paper proposed three different structures for 4-Bit digital comparator. The structures have common and special features. These structures have been compared in different aspects" --https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340755668_Three_Different_Structures_for_4-Bit_Digital_Comparator